# Trigger a named pipeline in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I would like to switch from my jenkins jobs to gitlab pipelines entirely.
However, some jobs are never executed as the result of a pipeline.
I would like to be able to trigger these jobs/tasks manually (e.g. by pressing a button or curl).

These manual jobs are intended to perform some source code modifications (such as dependency updates, creating tickets for external rollouts, ...) and create a MR as a result (which is then covered by the normal ci pipelines).

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to trigger these.
There is the trigger API, that allows to run the pipeliens for a certain branch, but I would like to trigger a pipeline only by name.
I explicitly don't want to rerun the default pipelines on these triggers.

I also considered using environments/deployments, but these tasks lack a real lifecycle and I don't wish to repurpose those for my needs.

TLDR: How do I trigger a job/pipeline by name?

```yaml
update-dependencies:
  only:
  - triggers
  script:
  - update-dependencies.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
  when: manual
```

**Example:**

```
update-dependencies:
  script:
  - update-dependencies.sh
  when: manual
```

***How it looks:***

[image]